# JavaScript promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I just started learning JavaScript and found this piece of code online:

```
var x = document.getElementById("pageBeginCountdown").value;

/* dont understand this line of code below */
ProgressCountdown(x, 'pageBeginCountdown', 'pageBeginCountdownText').then(value => audio.play());

function ProgressCountdown(timeleft, bar, text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
      timeleft--;

      document.getElementById(bar).value = timeleft;
      document.getElementById(text).textContent = timeleft;

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        resolve(true);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

I edit this line of code into:

```
ProgressCountdown(x, 'pageBeginCountdown', 'pageBeginCountdownText').then(value => record());
```

and I have a record function below:

```
function record() {
  startRecording();
  document.querySelector("#myText").innerHTML = "Recording..";
  document.querySelector("#pageBeginCountdownText").innerHTML = "";

  setTimeout(function() {
    stopRecording();
    document.querySelector("#myText").innerHTML = "Recording finished";
  }, 3000);
}
```

i thought that `value => audio.play()` is function so i replace it with record() function. Note that "pageBeginCountdown" is a html progress bar, and startRecording & stopRecording is in another js file call recorder.js.

The page does not work when i try to run it, nothing happens after the progress bar reaches 0.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>

<body id="page-top">

        <div class="row begin-countdown">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <progress value="5" max="5" id="pageBeginCountdown"></progress></br></br>
                <span id = "myText" style="color: red"> Prepare </span>
                <span id ="pageBeginCountdownText" style="color: red"> 5 </span></br>
          </div>
        </div>

            <div id="controls">
                    <button id="recordButton" style="display:none;" >Record</button>
                    <button id="pauseButton" disabled class="button">Pause</button>
                    <button id="stopButton" disabled class="button">Stop</button>                   
                </div></br>

                <div id="formats">Your Recording:</div>
                <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>           

<script src="/js/recorder.js"></script>
<script src="/js/record.js"></script>
<script src="/js/countrecord.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

and my countrecord.js :

```
var x = document.getElementById("pageBeginCountdown").value;

ProgressCountdown(x, 'pageBeginCountdown', 'pageBeginCountdownText').then(value => record());

function ProgressCountdown(timeleft, bar, text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
      timeleft--;

      document.getElementById(bar).value = timeleft;
      document.getElementById(text).textContent = timeleft;

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        resolve(true);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function record() {
  startRecording();
  document.querySelector("#myText").innerHTML = "Recording..";
  document.querySelector("#pageBeginCountdownText").innerHTML = "";

  setTimeout(function() {
    stopRecording();
    document.querySelector("#myText").innerHTML = "Recording finished";
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: But then, what do you make of `var audio = document.getElementById("player");` ?

Comment: Sorry I have removed that too, cause I don't have player element on my page. I will edit the question, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Should work providing `record()` is in scope and elements with those IDs exist on the page.

Comment: If you could provide us the `html` as well, it would help finding possible errors.

Comment: Hi i have edit the question including html and js.

Comment: Thanks guys its solved, I placed all files in same folder and it worked. Dont understand why but it works.

Comment: See those `<script src="/js/recorder.js"></script>` tags. If the `src` attribute is wrong, then the browser won't see the file.